# Magento get Wishlistitem from Product

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.9

```
public function addItem(Mage_Wishlist_Model_Item $item)
{

    $superAttributes = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('super_attribute');
    if ($item instanceof Mage_Wishlist_Model_Item && isset($superAttributes)) {
        $simpleItem = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getProductByAttributes($superAttributes, $item->getProduct());
    }

    return parent::addItem($simpleItem);
}
```

Now my problem is that i want to call the parent function which needs to receive an `Mage_Wishlist_Model_Item` not a `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product`

```
MyCustom_Wishlist_Model_Wishlist extends Mage_Wishlist_Model_Wishlist
```

How can i get the wishlistitem for the Product `$simpleItem`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function addItem(Mage_Wishlist_Model_Item $item)
{
    $superAttributes = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('super_attribute');
    if ($item instanceof Mage_Wishlist_Model_Item && isset($superAttributes)) {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getProductByAttributes($superAttributes, $item->getProduct());
        $item = Mage::getModel('wishlist/item');
        $storeId = $product->hasWishlistStoreId() ? $product->getWishlistStoreId() : $this->getStore()->getId();
        $qty = 1;

        $item->setProductId($product->getId())
            ->setWishlistId($this->getId())
            ->setAddedAt(now())
            ->setStoreId($storeId)
            ->setOptions($product->getCustomOptions())
            ->setProduct($product)
            ->setQty($qty)
            ->save();
    }

    return parent::addItem($item);
}
```

This works for me now but i didn't figure out how to set the `$qty` yet

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this URL?
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19678/how-do-i-add-to-wishlist-programatically

It's the native way to add a product to wishlist.

If you don't want to change the parameter type then you may remove the $item type check from your code (it's not necessary):

```
$item instanceof Mage_Wishlist_Model_Item
```

Hope it helps you.